# Как правильно сделать навигацию в Android?

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-architecture

Есть приложение, которое в себе содержит нижнюю навигацию через **BottomNavigationView**.

Как вариант можно использовать **Navigation Component**. Проблема в том, что данное решение не сохраняет состояние самих фрагментов. То есть каждый переход будет заново пересоздавать все элементы в макете, что для пользователя будет не совсем приятно. Особенно, это заметно, когда на фрагменте отображается сложный UI или тот же webView. Можно сохранять состояние фрагмента во вьюмоделе или использовать официальный костыль от гугла, но это не спасает от пересоздание фрагментов. Без нагромождения кода в navigation я не видел, чтобы можно было хайдить сами фрагменты.

Можно разумеется всё делать напрямую через **fragmentManager**, но есть ли какое-то готовое решение в виде библиотеки или конкретных паттернов по созданию навигации, которые возьмут на себя часть кода, чтобы спустя время навигация не стала больным местом проекта, где будет уже сложно поддерживать и расширять.

Как я понимаю хранить в памяти фрагменты не самая лучшая идея, но я видел во многих приложениях с нижней навигации, где переход между вкладками происходит за доли секунды без пересоздание фрагмента.

Смотрел в сторону **Cicerone**, но он был изначально написан под архитектуру MVP и я не смог найти адекватные проекты под MVVM с ним.

Каким образом вы делаете навигацию в своих проектах и каким образом вы боретесь с сохранением фрагмента? Буду благодарен, если вы скинете пример навигации или статьи по этому по поводу.

Comment: В одном своем проекте с BottomNavigation я создал просто три фрагмента и переключал их потегу через FragManager ручками с анимациями и вот этим всем.. Но там проект был небольшой и такой подход вполне годился да. В нескольких крупных проблема действительно имеет место быть и оставил так как есть увы

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сохранить состояние фрагмента, как вариант можно использовать

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

Если это вам не подходит, попробуйте взглянуть на данное решение.

https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample

Comment: Как раз этот гугловский костыль только сохраняет состояние фрагментов, всё равно пересоздает фрагмент. Поэтому пока более оптимальный вариант юзать navigation c viewPager

Comment: @ДмитрийПозолота https://medium.com/@oluwabukunmi.aluko/bottom-navigation-view-with-fragments-a074bfd08711 Вот еще есть способ. Я честно говоря не пробовал его, потому не ручаюсь за его эффективность, но вдруг вам поможет? Судя по видео-превью автора отсюда https://github.com/bukunmialuko/BottomNavViewWithFragments всё прогружается достаточно быстро.